# How to add ajax combobox properly in asp.net webform application

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

Right now i'm trying to use combobox in the application i'm working by following [this](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/combobox/combobox.aspx) page.
But when i run the page, only the dropdown is working but the auto suggestion feature is not working and also the text field is not editable. So how to do it?
Here is the code i'm using:

```
                            <cc1:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" 
                                 AutoPostBack="True" 
                                 DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 
                                 AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" 
                                 CaseSensitive="False" 
                                 CssClass="" 
                                 ItemInsertLocation="Append" > 
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Mild" Value="0" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="1" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Hot" Value="2" />
                            </cc1:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your DropDownStyle to Simple or DropDown and you'll get the desired result, here is the updated Code:

```
<cc1:ComboBox
  ID="ComboBox1"
  runat="server"
  AutoPostBack="True"
  DropDownStyle="Simple"
  AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
  CaseSensitive="False"
  CssClass=""
  ItemInsertLocation="Append">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Mild" Value="0" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="1" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Hot" Value="2" />
</cc1:ComboBox>
```